# Wordpress: how to get an image in more/excerpt?

Tags: wordpress

I need to make a homepage of a wordpress blog show just 1 paragraf of text followed by more, and below a big nice image.

However, excerpt does not take images.

Also, if i put the more page divider, no image appears. and even if it does, the 'more' link should be after the text, not after the image.

How can i get this to work?

UPDATE:
I noticed that in the source code, there is a link to an image, but it is not the right link. 
currently my blog is at www.domain.com/wordpress and will be moved to www.domain.com.

currently the image has the code:

```
<a href="../wp-content/uploads/2011/05/2010_06_01_archive.jpg"><img width="800" height="990" alt="" src="../wp-content/uploads/2011/05/2010_06_01_archive.jpg" title="2010_06_01_archive"></a>
```

Somehow the build-in linkage is broken

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use wordpress's in-built "featured image" (can be set on post's editing page in wordpress admin).

On the page displaying the excerpts:

```
<div id="excerpts">
    <?php
    $args = array( 'numberposts' => 3, 'category'=> '1,3,5' ); }
    // set number of excepts to show
    // and optionally restrict to certain categories
    $posts = get_posts($args);
    foreach($posts as $post) : setup_postdata($post);
    ?>
    <div class="single-excerpt">
        <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
        <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) the_post_thumbnail('excerpt-thumb'); ?>
        <!-- displays thumbnail if it exists -->
        <p><?php the_excerpt();?></p>
    </div><!-- single-excerpt -->
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div><!-- excerpts -->
```

In your theme's *functions.php*:

```
if ( function_exists( 'add_image_size' ) ) add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
if ( function_exists( 'add_image_size' ) ) { 
    add_image_size( 'excerpt-thumb', 0, 100, false );
    // define excerpt-thumb size here
    // in the example: 100px wide, height adjusts automatically, no cropping
}

function new_excerpt_length($length) {
    return 42;
    // define length of excerpt in number of words
}
add_filter('excerpt_length', 'new_excerpt_length');
```

Comment: so i can have a single homepage with multiple posts on it and each post will have their own featured image, is that right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. The above code will produce exactly that. Only caveat of `the_excerpt()` is that it comes unformatted. If you want post excerpts with paragraphs, you have to use `the_content()` and 'more' tags instead.

Comment: I am marking it as right, although i figured it out in a different way: `add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );` in functions and then `<?php the_post_thumbnail();?>` in the loop does the job

Answer (score -1):

You could also use the Wordpress plugin [Easy Custom Auto Excerpt](https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-custom-auto-excerpt/) which allows you to configure the excerpt to include shortcode, images, and all HTML.

Answer (score -3):

Make sure the image is properly sized, and the physical size is minimized as much as possible.  (Gif is usually the best format for this.)

http://codex.wordpress.org/Image_Size_and_Quality

Comment: I don't think it's a matter of size/quality. I added more info and source code